# Trying to open a form into an html file

Tags: php, html, tabs, href

I have this open source project, written in php, and I am trying to modify the code. I added some tabs and I want to load a form when a tab is selected. The project is OpenEMR.

```
   <?php
 if($focustype=='allergy'){
 ?>
    <div id="container">
        <ul class="tabNav">
            <li class="current"><a href="/play/javascript-tabbed-navigation/">Medical Implants</a></li>             
        </ul>
       <div class="tabContainer">
        <div class="tab current">
            <p><a id="cod2" onclick="return loadFrame2('cod2','RBot','patient_file/encounter/load_form.php?formname=LBFclinicalPD')" href="" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Patient Clinical Data</a><p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
```

The problem is that it doesn't work. It seems to be loading for a second and then nothing.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have the Javascript code for loadframe2?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a id="cod2" onclick="loadFrame2('cod2','RBot','patient_file/encounter/load_form.php?formname=LBFclinicalPD');return false;" href="#" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Patient Clinical Data</a>
```

Comment: I try it. It doesn't work... I try to open the form under tabs, load it into tag content.